# Android ListView Adaptor changing colour when you scroll past the item

Tags: java, android, android-adapter

Okay so we have some realm results returning a set of stock orders that we have made. Depending on if the stock order is fully checked in we are showing the background colour of the row item as green or blue using an if statement in the adaptor.

The issue is that on load the orders display as green/blue correctly. But when you scroll down the blue ones are changing to green. (See Images). We think it may be that the data is getting changed somewhere but not sure why this would be happening as we are just scrolling on the page.

[image: Before scroll]
[image: After scroll]

Code that creates this:

*StockOrdersFragment.java*

```
@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    myView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.stock_orders_layout, container, false);
    listView = myView.findViewById(R.id.listView);

    stockOrdersService = new StockOrdersService(this);

    stockOrdersService.fetchFromServer(getActivity());

    fetchStockOrders();

    return myView;
}

public void fetchStockOrders()
{
    stockOrders.clear();

    RealmResults<StockOrder> savedStockOrders = stockOrdersService.all();

    stockOrders.addAll(savedStockOrders);

    StockOrdersAdaptor adaptor = new StockOrdersAdaptor(stockOrders, getActivity());

    listView.setAdapter(adaptor);
}

@Override
public void ordersReceived() {
    fetchStockOrders();
}
```

*StockOrdersAdaptor.java (The bit that does the colour )*

```
lastPosition = position;

if(stockOrder != null){
    viewHolder.stockOrderId.setText(String.valueOf(stockOrder.id));
    viewHolder.supplierName.setText(stockOrder.supplier.name);

    if (stockOrder.allItemsHaveBeenReceived()) {
        convertView.setBackgroundResource(R.color.colorGreen);
    }
}

// Return the completed view to render on screen
return convertView;
```

*The allItemsHaveBeenRecieved()*

```
public Boolean allItemsHaveBeenReceived()
{
    for (StockOrderDetails detail: details) {
        if (detail.quantity != detail.quantityReceived) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: You should show more of getView(). Where did you set the blue color?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add else statement here:

```
if (stockOrder.allItemsHaveBeenReceived()) {
    convertView.setBackgroundResource(R.color.colorGreen);
} else {
    convertView.setBackgroundResource(R.color.colorBlue);
}
```

Problem is when your item gets recycled it remains dirty. Make sure you are populating **all** UI items from your list item layout every time adapter binds to it.